# Facebook iOS SDK: session invalid on iPhone after logging out of Facebook from a desktop

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, session, fbconnect

I recently integrated Facebook support into an iPhone application that I work on.  I'm able to log the user in and make API calls fine, but I recently noticed some strange behavior.

After the user logs in I store the access token and the expiration date in NSUserDefaults.  Before executing Facebook API calls I use [session isSessionValid] to make sure the session is valid.

The problem occurs if the user logs into Facebook from a desktop and then logs out.  [session isSessionValid] still returns YES, but Facebook API calls fail with the error:

"Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error."

Is there anything that I am doing wrong, or is this a Facebook bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you store the access token and the expiration date in NSUserDefaults, you need to validate them when the user enters your app each time, even offline_access permission access tokens might be invalidated for example when users change their password.

When your app is started you just need to make a call to graph API "me" and in case you get exception you need simply to re-authorize, then you proceed with regular workflow of API calls.

hope this helps

Comment: This is fine, I'd like to add up that you also need to logout and remove access token info from disk when receiving an access token exception, then re-authorize.

Comment: Thanks.  I added code to re-authorize upon the error and it seems to be working fine.